# (SystemJS) Unexpected token < ( ASP.net + Angular 4)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angular

Not sure how to fix this issue; I'm trying to use ngx-translate to dynamically load my localization values.
It's an asp.net with angular 4.
Here is my System.config.js

```
(function (global) {
System.config({
    paths: {
        // paths serve as alias
        'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
        // our app is within the app folder
        app: '/app',

        // angular bundles
        '@ngx-translate/core': 'npm:@ngx-translate/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
        '@ngx-translate/http-loader': 'npm:@ngx-translate/http-loader/bundles/http-loader.umd.js',
        '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
        '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
        '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
        '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
        '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
        '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
        '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
        '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
        // other libraries
        'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
        'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js'
        
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
        app: {
            main: 'main.js', defaultExtension: 'js',
                meta: {
      './*.js': {
            loader: 'systemjs-angular-loader.js'
        }
    }
        },
        rxjs: {
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        }
       
    }
});
})(this);
```

This is my app module:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'

 import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from "@ngx-translate/core";
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from "@ngx-translate/http-loader";
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";

// AoT requires an exported function for factories
export function HttpLoaderFactory(httpClient: HttpClient) {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(httpClient, "i18n/", ".json");
}

@NgModule({
declarations: [
     AppComponent
],
imports: [
  BrowserModule, FormsModule, AppRoutingModule, TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
          provide: TranslateLoader,
          useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
          deps: [HttpClient]
      }
  })
  ],
  providers: [],
 bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
 export class AppModule { }
```

This is the example I'm trying to follow.
https://plnkr.co/edit/WccVZSBM0rUgq2sXSUbe?p=preview

This is the error I'm getting

```
Error: (SystemJS) Unexpected token <
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
        at eval (<anonymous>)
        at Object.eval (http://localhost:63021/app/app.module.js:25:14)
        at eval (http://localhost:63021/app/app.module.js:69:4)
        at eval (http://localhost:63021/app/app.module.js:70:3)
    Evaluating http://localhost:63021/@ngx-translate/core
    Evaluating http://localhost:63021/app/app.module.js
    Evaluating http://localhost:63021/app/main.js
    Error loading http://localhost:63021/app/main.js
        at eval (<anonymous>)
        at Object.eval (http://localhost:63021/app/app.module.js:25:14)
        at eval (http://localhost:63021/app/app.module.js:69:4)
        at eval (http://localhost:63021/app/app.module.js:70:3)
    Evaluating http://localhost:63021/@ngx-translate/core
    Evaluating http://localhost:63021/app/app.module.js
    Evaluating http://localhost:63021/app/main.js
    Error loading http://localhost:63021/app/main.js
```

My Main.ts

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';


platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

My project structure
[image: Project Structure]

Comment: do you have a main.ts file?can you share the code?Also what is the folder structure of your project of `app`

Comment: are you sure this path is correct for your `app` folder `map: {
        // our app is within the app folder
        app: '/app',` Should it be `app: 'app'` ?

Comment: I haven't looked carefully through your code, but often 'unexpected token <' is because you are not loading the javascript file you think you should be, and are instead loading a 404 page or other html file. Take a look at the file that is being loaded and throwing the error and see if that points you in the correct direction.

Comment: I just added my main.ts and my project folder structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http and HttpClient are two different module( under angular 4.3.4)

Add to systemjs.config.js:

```
map: {
       ;
        '@angular/common/http': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common-http.umd.js',
        'tslib': 'npm:tslib/tslib.js',
```

Add to your app.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
     declarations: [AppComponent],
     imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule,HttpClientModule, AppRoutingModule, TranslateModule.forRoot({
```

See [here](https://github.com/Longfld/ASPNETcoreAngularJWT) for more details